# Sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)$ that converges to the zero function and $\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx$ increases without a bound

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is it possible to find:

> Sequence of continuous functions $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
>   that converges to the zero function and such that sequence $\int_0^1
>  f_1(x)dx, \int_0^1 f_2(x)dx,\ldots$ increases without a bound

I think it's quite easy. Just define $f_n$ in the following way:

[image]

> Uniformly convergent sequence of differentiable functions $f_n :
>  (0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the sequence $f_1 ',
> f_2',\ldots$ does not converge.

Here I have trouble.

> Convergent sequence of Riemann integrable functions $f_n :
>  [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose limit function IS NOT Riemann integrable.

I know the example that uses charactersitic function of rationals. But is it possible to give another example?

Comment: Your first example doesn't converge at $0$; but that's easily fixed ( /\ ).

Comment: cHere I wrote up some continuous functions that have constant integral but converge pointwise to zero: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553955/simple-sequence-of-functions/1558185#1558185 If you multiply the function $f_n$ by n pointwise convergence to zero will still be given but the integral will diverge.

Comment: @David Could you tell me how it can be fixed?

Comment: @s.harp, i will take a look

Comment: Just make the graph look like what I wrote at the end of my first comment.

Comment: @DavidMitra I'm sorry, but I can't see how that will work... I want to make the area of triangle arbitrary large, but keep $(f_n)$ convergent to $0$. It's counterintuitive to me.

Comment: The triangle will have vertices at the origin, $(1/(2n),2n^2)$, and $(1/n,0)$. Its area will be ${1\over 2}\cdot 2n^2\cdot{1\over n}=n$.

Comment: And it will still converge to $0$, of course.

Comment: @DavidMitra how does your function converge pointwise to zero? I see that the area diverges but I fail to see how it is pointwise convergent to zero.

Comment: @MrStormy83 My $f_n$ has value 0 on $(1/n,1 ]$ and at the point 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(second question) $f_n(x)=\frac1n\sin(n^2x)$

(third question) $f_n(x)=1/x$ on $[1/n,1]$ and $n^2x$ on $[0,1/n].$

Comment: (i) has finite integral on $[0,1]$, (ii) is not continuous.

Comment: It is not clear from the question that the integral condition applies to the second question and that the continuity requirement applies to the third question.

Comment: Ah, I think you messed up your numbering, (i) is (ii) and (ii) is (iii) ;)

Comment: I still managed to make the last example continuous :-)

Comment: Each question is separate :) Thanks.

Comment: Done, and I have clarified my numbering :-)

Comment: @Justpassingby maybe that is a stupid question, but what is the limit of sequence of functions in third question?